# Python basics printing 1 to 100

Tags: python

```
def gukan(count):
    while count!=100:
      print(count)
      count=count+1;
gukan(0)
```

My question is: When I try to increment by 3 or 9 instead of 1 in `count=count+1` I get an infinite loop - why is that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem cannot be reproduced with the code in question.

Comment: Do you mean 3 or 9 in this line: `count=count+1; ` instead of the 1?

Comment: no its not !@thefourtheye

Comment: @M4rtini: Nice one; that's probably what the OP meant.

Comment: yes ! in that line only @M4rtini

Comment: he means when you increment by 3 or 9, saying this is off topic is a bit harsh its just a newbie question, quite a common one but I think valid so +1 for that.

Comment: @krystanhonour to be fair to the close-voters - the original revision of this post didn't state that and this was a question with a non-reproducible issue...

Comment: i don't understand why this question had a 4 up votes?

Answer (score 31):

The answers here have pointed out that because after incrementing count it doesn't equal **exactly** 100, then it keeps going as the criteria isn't met (it's likely you want `<` to say *less than* 100).

I'll just add that you should really be looking at Python's builtin `range` function which generates a sequence of integers from a starting value, *up to* (but not including) another value, and an optional *step* - so you can adjust from adding 1 or 3 or 9 at a time...

0-100 (but not including 100, defaults starting from 0 and stepping by 1):

```
for number in range(100):
    print(number)
```

0-100 (but not including and makes sure number doesn't go above 100) in steps of 3:

```
for number in range(0, 100, 3):
    print(number)
```

Answer (score 10):

When you change `count = count + 1` to `count = count + 3` or `count = count + 9`, `count` will never be equal to 100. At the very best it'll be 99. That's not enough.

What you've got here is the classic case of infinite loop: `count` is never *equal* to 100 (sure, at some point it'll be greater than 100, but your `while` loop doesn't check for this condition) and the `while` loop goes on and on.

What you want is probably:

```
while count < 100: # Or <=, if you feel like printing a hundred.
```

Not:

```
while count != 0:  # Spaces around !=. Makes Guido van Rossum happy.
```

Now the loop will terminate when `count >= 100`.

Take a look at Python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while).

Comment: Yet this would only explain the problem the OP is facing if they started with `gukan(101)` or higher.

Comment: Ah, but if the OP used `+ 3` or `+ 9` then indeed, the loop would be infinite.

Comment: He could check for divisibility of the difference of the end value and the start value by the increment to avoid that >;-]

Answer (score 4):

The first line defines the variable. The second line loops it to 100, the third adds 1 to a and the 4th divides a by 3 and if there is no remainder (0) it will print that number otherwise it will print a blank line.

```
 a = (0)

for i in range(0,100):
     a = a + 1
if a % 3 == 0:
    print(a)
else:
    print("")
```

Answer (score 1):

For this question, we have to first understand what does range and while looping mean.
here we are incrementing the value of i by 1,

```
def gukan(count):
    while count!=100:
      print(count)
      count=count+1;
gukan(0)
```

so at one point of time after incrementing we have a condition where

```
i =100
```

so the loop breaks.
whereas when we use increment value to be any odd number except multiples of 5,

```
def gukan(count):
    while count!=100:
      print(count)
      count=count+9;
gukan(0)
```

we will never have a condition where i=100, so this results to an infinite loop.

output:

```
0
9
18
27
36
45
54
63
72
81
90
99
108
117
126 ... till infinite
```

Answer (score 0):

Your count never equals the value 100 so your loop will continue until that is true

Replace your while clause with

```
def gukan(count):
    while count < 100:
      print(count)
      count=count+3;
gukan(0)
```

and this will fix your problem, the program is executing correctly given the conditions you have given it.

Comment: @Alexis: there *is* a `1` in the OP code. On the line `count=count+1`.

Answer (score 0):

because if you change your code with

```
def gukan(count):
    while count!=100:
      print(count)
      count=count+3;
gukan(0)
```

count reaches 99 and then, at the next iteration 102.

So

```
count != 100
```

never evaluates true and the loop continues forever

If you want to count up to 100 you may use

```
def gukan(count):
    while count <= 100:
      print(count)
      count=count+3;
gukan(0)
```

or (if you want 100 always printed)

```
def gukan(count):
    while count <= 100:
      print(count)
      count=count+3;
      if count > 100:
          count = 100
gukan(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

consider the following:

```
def gukan(count):
    while count < 100:
      print(count)
      count=count+3;
gukan(0) #prints ..., 93, 96, 99


def gukan(count):
    while count < 100:
      print(count)
      count=count+9;
gukan(0) # prints ..., 81, 90, 99
```

you should use `count < 100` because `count` will never reach the exact number 100 if you use 3 or 9 as the increment, thus creating an infinite loop.

Good luck!~ :)

Answer (score -1):

x=1
while x<=100:
    print(x)
    x=x+3

Comment: This looks to be covered pretty well in the other answers

Answer (score -1):

I think `Simplest way` is :

```
for counter in range(1,101):
    print(counter)
```

output

```
1
2
3
.
.
98
99
100
```

Answer (score -2):

When you use count = count + 3 or count = count + 9 instead of count = count + 1, the value of count will never be 100, and hence it enters an infinite loop.

You could use the following code for your condition to work

while count < 100:

Now the loop will terminate when count >= 100.

Answer (score -2):

To print all the numbers from 1 to 100 simply code:

```
counter = 1
while counter < 101:
   print(counter)
   counter += 1
```

Answer (score -3):

Because the condition is never true.
i.e. count !=100 never executes when you put count=count+3 or count =count+9.
try this out..`while count<100`

Answer (score -3):

I would guess it makes an infinite loop bc you skip the number 100. If you set the critera to be less than 101 it should do the trick :)

```
def gukan(count):
    while count<100:
      print(count)
      count=count+3;
gukan(0)
```

Answer (score -3):

Consider this easiest way

```
a = (0)

for i in range(0,100):
     a = a + 1
if a % 3 == 0:
    print(a)
else:
    print("")
```

Comment: There is a lot of scope of improvement in this answer.

Comment: This has to be a GPT generated code or something like that.